# Constructing a sequence with certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Do there exist a sequence $(a_n)$ satisfying $0<|a_n|<1$ for $n\geq 1$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}(1-|a_n|)<\infty$ such that any point on $\partial B(0,1)$ is a cluster point of the set $\{a_n\}$?

Comment: Enumerate rational angles on the circle and spread them as arguments with absolute values your favorite sequence that works - e.g. $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @Conrad Indeed, this works for the conditions. I am having troubles to see if each point on the boundary is a cluster point of the set of terms. Given $a\in \partial B(0,1)$, I must verify that $(B(a,r)\cap \{a_n\})\setminus \{a\}\neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$. Could you help me with one?

Comment: Just pick a non constant sequence of rational angles going to your angle; since by construction the absolute values go to $1$ you are done - formally if you fix $r$  both angles and absolute values are inside that ball if close enough